# ASP.Net session expired in other tabs

Tags: asp.net, webforms

ASP.Net session expired in other tabs.

example I opened up two tabs, one tab item master, another purchase order.

long time working on purchase order tab, but suddenly purchase order tab logout becoz i did not work in item tab since more than 30 min then item tab log out and clear all the sessions so purchase order tab also logout.

what is the solution.

Thanks
Basit.

Comment: Do you have any javascript code running that forces a logoff after some non-active period?

Comment: Yes that code in master page

Comment: *that* code is responsible for the logout action, not webforms by itself. So you will need to study that to see if you can stop logout when other tabs are active